# How would I define this predicate as a function?

Tags: c#, .net, predicate

Not sure if I have the title right on this one, feel free to correct me.

I have code similar to the following:

```
string myValue = "aaa";
List<ListItem> myList = CreateMyList();
myList.Find(t=>t.Value == myValue );
```

I would like to create a Predicate function that does the same thing.  I am able to implement it if I do not need to pass in `myValue`:

```
   ...
   List<ListItem> myList = CreateMyList();
   myList.Find(SelectByValue);
   ...
}

static bool SelectByValue(ListItem li)
{                      //***myValue is now hardcoded***
    return li.Value == "aaa";
}
```

But I would like to be able to specify what "aaa" should be when I make the call to the predicate function.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than returning a bool, make it return a `Predicate<ListItem>`:

```
static Predicate<ListItem> SelectByValue(String target)
{
    return delegate(ListItem li) { return li.Value == target; };
}
```

Then *call* the method:

```
myList.Find(SelectByValue("foo"));
```

Note that C# 3 introduces lambda expressions making this slightly simpler:

```
static Predicate<ListItem> SelectByValue(String target)
{
    return li => li.Value == target;
}
```

... and in .NET 3.5 and higher, it's generally more idiomatic to use LINQ than the `List<T>`-specific methods.

Answer (score 3):

```
static Predicate<ListItem> SelectByValue(string value)
{
    return item=>li.Value == value;
}
```